# How to pass argument from module A to module B?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJs and I try to use a one page/one module pattern with one super module on the index.

Right now, I have a route to open a page which display a a specific recipe.
I am able to display my page using routing. I've put a parameter in my route, but I can't access my parameter in my recipe_module.

Here is my code :

my index module

```
var layout = angular.module( 'LayoutApp', [
                                    // Dépendances du "module"
                                    'ngRoute',
                                    'RecipeDetailsApp'
                                        ]);
layout.config( [ '$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {
    $routeProvider
        .when( '/recettes_details/:idRecette', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/recettes_details.html',
        } );
}]);
```

my recipe module :

```
var RecipeDetails = angular.module( 'RecipeDetailsApp', [ 'ngFactoryApp', 'ngRoute' ] );

RecipeDetails.controller( 'RecipeDetailsCtrl', [ 'ngFactory', function( ngFactory, $routeParams ) {
this.recipeId = $routeParams.param;

}]);
```

And finally my recipe HTML

```
<div ng-app="RecipeDetailsApp" ng-controller="RecipeDetailsCtrl as recipeDetailsCtrl">
    <h1> {{RecipeDetailsCtrl.recipeId}}</h1>
</div>
```

How can I provide any parameters to my recipe_module without using a $scope variable?
Thanks

Comment: You could use a shared service that both apps depend on to communicate between the 2.

Comment: That was my second idea. But it seems weird that you cannot pass a parameter from a page to another, especially when the angular doc tells you to create at least as many module as you have pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally understood my mistake.
I just had a bad injection syntax... I wrote :

```
RecipeDetails.controller( 'RecipeDetailsCtrl', [ 'ngFactory', function( ngFactory, $routeParams ) {
this.recipeId = $routeParams.param;

}]);
```

where I should have written :

```
RecipeDetails.controller( 'RecipeDetailsCtrl', '$routeParams, [ 'ngFactory', function( ngFactory, $routeParams ) {
this.recipeId = $routeParams.param;

}]);
```

and now, I can send parameter from a page to another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a module that contains all stuff (services, directives, filters) that is going to be common to all the modules and include it in the modules you require.

Something like:

```
angular.module('Common',[])
.factory('Common.utilsSvc', function(){

})
```

And then use the Common module in yours:

```
var layout = angular.module( 'LayoutApp', ['Common']);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I actually have a common factory for some specific task (like getting data from a json file).
But, passing a parameter from a page to another isn't what it should be used for.
It does not feel right to add to create a factory just for that nor adding parameters for a quick "hack"